# Mining on Nvidia(i know it's bad, but it's a start)

Tags: litecoin

So, I have this nvidia geforce fx5200 d256m gpu in an old box, I want to start it out as a no-cost minig rig(laugh all you want, I'm starting base and hoping to spend zero out of the pocket). I wanted to know what the expected hashrate would be, and what kind of settings I should set it up to use with in cgminer. 
Remember people, the question is about the card, not my ideas of what I'm doing. Also this is planing to be done in my basement, which is always cold. So airflow/temp isn't an issue either. It's mining ***litecoins*** NOT bitcoins.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LiteCoin Rig Mining Hardware](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5939/litecoin-rig-mining-hardware)

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a comparison chart.](http://litecoin.info/Mining_Hardware_Comparison)  Your card is not even on there. So I assume its going to be about 5khs if you lucky.

I would suggest you sell that card even for five bucks and invest in AMD card with loads of cuda cores. Its obvious you don't want to spend lots of money but for 50 bucks you can find a decent card on eBay or something. That will give you allot more kh/s.

The problem with GFX mining is that electricity is really expensive. If you dont have to pay for it or you are within a green area (Hydro plants, Solar Power) and its "dirt" cheap then it is still worth it.

Good luck with your experiment.

*FYI - I would suggest looking into ASIC Erupter for ultra low power BITCOIN miners.*

[image]

*Or you sell everything and stack the pennies up order one of these 5GHs "Jalapeno" miners  from Butterfly LABS. They can be "jail borken" and even go to 9ghs if you add extra fans.*

[image]

<sup>I am in no way affiliated with any of these companies. I just use their stuff and I know it works and brings me money in. No BS!</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Previous poster was correct on Grabbing and AMD  card. But no Cuda on AMD cards. That is Nvidia. As far as your card. You will need to install the cuda tools to get it going and yea, looking at 2-5K

Comment: -1 It is hard to tell what you are trying to say. Please provide all information for your answer to stand by itself (don't refer to other answers) and clarify your answer's meaning.